# Ember Data FilterBy

Tags: firebase, ember-data

I am trying to filter the data coming back from FindAll cause I only want data from a certain provider

```
// Data coming back from API
{
  "-KDinaItb7lkHpai-DlG": {
    "email": "johns@test.com",
    "name": "John Smith",
    "notes": "John is a great employee and is the best",
    "phone": "215-543-9830",
    "provider": "-KDhzbilOvv7Evuc5S_X"
  },
  "-KDjS0cCxFWQctcwXg0V": {
    "email": "amanda@test.com",
    "name": "Amanda Harrington",
    "notes": "Amanda is a great employee",
    "phone": "215-543-9830",
    "provider": "-KDiokWebdhTNKTORWwn"
  },
  "-KDyf7pU_PyxRQSgFB59": {
    "email": "lguy@test.com",
    "name": "Larry Guy",
    "notes": "He is a funny guy",
    "phone": "702-454-2397",
    "provider": "-KDhzbilOvv7Evuc5S_X"
  }
}

// In the route
let providerId = model.get('provider').get('id');
​
this.store.findAll('employee').then(function(results) {
  let prov = results.filterBy('provider', providerId);
​
  console.log(prov);
});
```

When the console log happens and it returns an empty array. I think its because of the ID and its not looking at the nested object. Anyone got any thoughts?

Comment: `filterBy` works on array not on objects. Ask sever side guy to send it as Array.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so your hash looks quite odd. Property name shouldn't be some generated hash.

code should be something like that.
I assume you have 1 wrapper object on index 0 within an array.

```
var filteredEmployees_promise = this.store.findAll('employee').then(function(results) {
   var filteredResults = [];
   Object.keys(Results[0]).forEach(key => {
     var filteredObj = Results[0][key][providerId];
     if(Ember.isPresent(filteredObj) {
        filteredResults.pushObject(filteredObj)
     }
   });
   return filteredResults;
});
```

And later

```
filterEmployees_promise.then(employees => { // Custom stuff })
```